# Ignore empty rows from a loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script and I'm trying to ignore the empty rows from a for loop, but I'm still getting the empty rows in my `log`. Here are my codes,

```
function getNonEmptyRows() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Bldng4");

    var lr = sheet1.getLastRow() - 17;

    for (var i = 1; i < lr; i++) {
        var singleRow = sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        if (singleRow.length > 0) {
            Logger.log(singleRow);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the only non empty rows from the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var range_data = 
          sheet1.getRange("A2:A") //Column Range
          .getValues() //Get array from range values
          .filter(array=>array != '') //Filter non-empty values
```

Comment: Hi. This answer is probably right,  but it would be a good idea to explain what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to a similar problem and here is what I did:
first, I found [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) on how to create google apps script to eliminate duplicate rows.
next, i modified it like this to eliminate empty rows:

```
function removeEmptyRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("settings");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:D").getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var empty = false;
    for(i in data){
      if(row.toString() == ",,,"){
        empty = true;
      }
    }
    if(!empty){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  sheet.getRange(2, 6, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
};
```

As you can see, it takes A2:D range, removes empty rows and then pastes filtered data without empty rows into range F2:I.
You can try to use this script, but you may need to adjust it to "width" of your array. To do so change the number of commas in the following string:

```
if(row.toString() == ",,,"){
```

**edit:**
I modified script a bit to automatically adjust to width of your array:

```
function removeEmptyRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("settings");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C");
  var data = range.getValues();
  var dataWidth = range.getWidth();
  var newData = new Array();
  if (dataWidth<=1) {
    var stringToCompare = '';
  }else{
    var stringToCompare = ',';
    for (var i=0;i<dataWidth-2;i++) stringToCompare+=","
  };
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var empty = false;
    for(i in data){
      if(row.toString() == stringToCompare){
        empty = true;
      }
    }
    if(!empty){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 6, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getValues()` method you are using always return a 2 dimensions array, whatever the contents of the cells might be. There are several ways to get the cells content, one of them is to stringify the range content (convert matrix to single string) , remove the commas (and eventually "invisible" spaces) and check the length of the resulting string.

replacement code could go like this :

```
var singleRow = sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues().toString().replace(',','').replace(' ','');
```

That said, this code is very inefficient because it uses SpreadSheetApp service in each loop iteration  which is particularly slow.
You'll find better approches in the documentation about [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices).